# How can I make an object that is already animated follow a path correctly?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to make a 3d model that is already animated to follow a path.

Again, my model is already

[image]

I tried to shift select path -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> -> Follow Path or just add the follow path constrain, but no luck. I'm using a NurbsPath.

As a experiment I tried to do the same thing with a simple cube, and surprize is working ... what I'm doing wrong?

Demo file  -> http://flester.ro/demo.blend
Demo file2 -> http://flester.ro/demo1.blend

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: maybe switch the direction? Edit mode, then W > Switch Direction

Comment: Switching direction is the first thing I tried(and making sure normals are pointing in the right direction, and matching origin between path and object). I would preffer not to share the model. Thank you

Comment: you can only keep one face of your model if you don't want to share the whole thing  ;)

Comment: have you looked thru the constraints tab?

Comment: yes, nothing there. I made a short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWGrPyntQl4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: An object with animated transforms seems to work. It seems more info is needed to find out what is going wrong here. How is the object animated? How is it rigged? Is it controlled by other constraints, drivers, physics, anything else?

Comment: http://flester.ro/demo.blend . So I'm using 2 cameras. Once the spaceship is up it should starts to follow path. I know i can offset the start, but I don't understand why is not following the path, what am I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not parented to the path and doesn't have any constraint. To make it move along the path, you can simply parent it to the path, then select the path, in the *Graph Editor* > *N* panel > *Modifiers*, delete the *Generator*, then in *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*, give some *Frames*, like for example 100, then play with the *Evaluation Time* and put some keyframes to move your object along the path at the speed you want.

Comment: I have added the second failed attempt. If I parent it (object method) it is working but I can't offset it to start animating from frame 181 and is offseted. Check out the blend file if you have time. I didn't knew about Graph Editor Modifiers, thank you!

Comment: yes you can start from whatever frame you want, you just have to set all this with the Evaluation Time value in the Data panel of the curve, you put the value you want at the time you want

Comment: Indeed is working. Martin Z Thank you too. You both are right, but this answer is more complete because it tells you to delete the generator that is hidden and is causing issues.

Comment: yes, at one moment you must have used a follow path constraint that has created this generator

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things going wrong in the file. I believe you have timeline markers and cameras assigned to them mixed up, also some keyframes out of place.

To use a curve as a path, an object must be parented to it. You need to set the frame number to the amount of frames you want the path animation to take and then keyframe the Evaluation Time at 0 where you wish the animation to start and at the amount of frames after the amount of frames you wish it to move.

[image]

Comment: Markers are for camera, I don't see any problems with having markers. No keyframes are out of place. It is working if I parent it directly to path (parent -> object  - not "follow path" method)